# Choregraphe: How to change NAO's Chest and Feet LEDs

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

Pretty much what the title says. How can i change NAO's Chest and Feet LEDs. I know they support RGB but how do i command what colours they stay at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. It was actually quite simple.

I altered the code of the "Eye LEDs" box.

If you double click it it will show you 2 other boxes, "Color Edit" and "Eyes LEDs".

I simply altered the code of the second "Eyes LEDs" box with this one:

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
def __init__(self):
    GeneratedClass.__init__(self, False)

def onLoad(self):
    self.fadeOps = []
    self.leds = self.session().service("ALLeds")

def onUnload(self):
    #~ puts code for box cleanup here
    pass

def onInput_color(self, p):
    if( self.getParameter("Side") == "Left" ):
        sGroup = "AllLeds"
    elif( self.getParameter("Side") == "Right" ):
        sGroup = "AllLeds"
    else:
        sGroup = "AllLeds"
    fadeOp = self.leds.fadeRGB(sGroup, 256*256*p[0] + 256*p[1] + p[2], self.getParameter("Duration (s)"), _async=True)
    self.fadeOps.append(fadeOp)
    fadeOp.wait()
    self.fadeOps.remove(fadeOp)
    if( self.fadeOps == [] ):
        self.onDone() # activate output of the box
```

Technically all I did is change all the "sGroup = ... " to sGroup = "AllLeds"